# DateTimePicker Bootstrap: shows only hours not days

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the datetime picker bootstrap, attempting to work with a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format.

As you can see from my screenshot, will be shown only the time in AM/PM format instead of the desired one:

[image]

If I click on the calendar icon, won't be shown anything but the clock icon.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="datatestform">
  <label for="datatest">Data di test:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>    
    <input id="datatest" type="data" class="form-control" name="datatest" value="10/10/2018 22:00" />    
  </div>  
</div>
```

And the JS, loaded at "document ready":

```
$("#datatest .input-group.date").datetimepicker({  
  defaultDate: $('#datatest').val(),
  inline: true,
  sideBySide: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#datatest .input-group.date').datetimepicker({
        format: "DD/MMM/YYYY",
        minDate: new Date(),
        useCurrent: false
    });
```

try this one.

Comment: Same problem, now doesn't appear nothing.

Comment: it's working fine in my code, why you have added value in html element, are you referencing jquery library.

Comment: change the input type of html element to "text" and try.

Comment: Changing the input type to "text" let it won't work.
I've added the default value in jQuery to be sure.

By the way it doesn't work.

Comment: what default value do you required? did you removed and tried ? may i know your jquery reference file name(library name)

Comment: The default value set in HTML.

I removed the default value from HTML and jQuery both, but with your code, moreover not showing the time, the popup dialog is empty.

jQuery library used is the standard one.

Comment: just try with id, remove class name in jquery code.

Comment: are you getting date and calender's?

Comment: if your getting the days then change the format in jquery , you will get time also.

Comment: No, as described in the question, I can't see no date, also with your solution.

Using only the id removing the class maintain the same problem

Comment: i am unable to get what your doing ? can you please comment your library file name. please follow the below link           https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

Comment: I followed that code and doesn't work.
I followed your suggestions getting the same result's error in my answer, that's all.

The library file name: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: is your jquery library loading in your pgae. i have used same thing in so many places in my project. it's working good for me.

Comment: It isn't probable: the other components work properly.

Comment: please download library file from this     .....    https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: I've switched to yours, with same result.

Comment: where you have added jquery function inside the document.ready or outside?

Comment: hey, i have checked in jsfiddle. your code is working fine

Comment: then problem with your reference file. please check in console weather script file is loading or not.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/288/) for running demo.

HTML Code -

```
<div class="form-group" id="datatestform">
<label for="datatest">Data di test:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input id="datatest" type="data" class="form-control" name="datatest" value="10/10/2018 22:00" />
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code -

```
$("#datatest").datetimepicker({
    maxDate: moment(),
    allowInputToggle: true,
    enabledHours : false,
    locale: moment().local('en'),
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm'
});
```

Comment: Same result: It won't be shown the calendar.

Moreover, I'll find this value inside the input field as default: Tu/10/yyyy 10:ii

Comment: @Istorn Have you go through the JSFiddle link that I provided in answer? It seems working in my system.

Comment: Please open JSFiddle link in other browser or try to clear your browser cache and try again to run the code. @Istorn

Comment: Also, you can make a JSFiddle of your code so that anyone can see where it fails. @Istorn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176130/discussion-between-shubham-baranwal-and-istorn).